# How to run a docker image in openshift origin without building it via web console

Tags: git, docker, openshift, openshift-origin, docker-image

I have a docker image developed and pushed onto the docker registry in openshift. Now I need to run the docker image as it is by passing some ENV variables. As shown below my docker image "mycustomdaemon:latest" was listed when I clicked "Add to project" link.

[image: My Docker Image Listed in apps]

However when I clicked on the image, it asked me to provide the build configuration and a Git repository URL as shown in the image below:

[image]

However I just need to run the image and do not want to rebuild it or perform any such actions. How would I be able to work around with it to simply run a Custom docker image created without performing any manipulation operations?

I tried to run the image directly from the CLI by issuing the `oc new-app` command but got the following error output.

> error: can't look up Docker image "172.30.55.11:5000/default/mycustomdaemon:latest": Internal error occurred: Get https://172.30.55.11:5000/v2/: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
>   error: no match for "172.30.55.11:5000/default/mycustomdaemon:latest"

[image: error when issuing oc new-app command]

`oc get is` command produces the following output:

[image: output of oc get is command]

Comment: which openshift version are you using? In version 3.3 there is an option "deploy image"

Comment: @ÁlvaroPérezSoria: I'm using openshift v1.2.0
**[root@mymachine ~]# `openshift version`**
**openshift v1.2.0**
**kubernetes v1.2.0-36-g4a3f9c5**
**etcd 2.2.5**

Comment: I see you edited the question. Do you have your internal registry, added as insecure registry in docker configuration?

Comment: Yes.. I added some more details to the question.. I had added as insecure registry in docker configuration. The problem was solved as @lorenzvth7 suggested i.e. I had to execute `oadm policy add-scc-to-user anyuid -z default` and then re-deploy it.. it solved the issue..! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me worked the following on `1.2.0`
First a I create a project in OpenShift in which I want to use my image.

```
$ oc new-project my-proj
```

Than I create an image-stream inside that project like described in [here](https://blog.openshift.com/remotely-push-pull-container-images-openshift/)

```
$ oc project my-proj
```

Create the image-stream

```
$ oc create -f - <<API

apiVersion: v1

kind: ImageStream

metadata:

  annotations:

    description: Keeps track of changes in the application image

  name: myimage

API
```

`name:` contains the name of your image
Than I tag my image. Authenticate on the openshift registry and push the image.

authenticate

```
$ docker login -u test -e any@mail.com ....
```

tag my image:

```
$ docker tag original-image:latest 172.30.x.x/my-proj/myimage:latest
```

push the image

```
$ docker push 172.30.x.x/my-proj/myimage:latest
```

You can push from inside your environment (just use service-ip) or from outside (use the hostname of your secured registry).

After that I'm able to create a pod/container of my image inside my openshift project:

```
$ oc project my-proj
$ oc new-app my-proj/myimage:latest
```

Comment: Thanks @lorenzvth7 .. But when I run it I get the following error when I look up at the status of the pod: **Status: Crash loop back off**

Comment: Which user is running inside your container? (is it root?)

Comment: yes its root user.. I have granted all the privileges to run it as root via oadm policy as well..!

Comment: When i run the pod via `oc run` command it works fine and the pod is created.. But since I want to deploy it as a pod within a service i get this error..

Comment: It's not recommended to run a container as root. But if you really want to do it (I need it too in a dev environment). I had to perform `oadm policy add-scc-to-user anyuid -z default` and scale my container down (if it's really hanging I had to redeploy it).

Comment: thanks a lot.. that helped and I could deploy it..!! :)

Comment: No problem. Maybe you can approve the answer :)

Comment: lorenzvth7.. I have a function inside my container which creates some files and folders for running certain commands. However, the files so created are corrupted when I run it in openshift.. Do I need to get any other privileges or perform any other authorization activities?? Although I was able to bring up the pods, the functionalities are not working now due to this error..! :(

Comment: Is it all working fine in docker (without openshift)?

Comment: well.. on machine with RHEL v 7.X it is not.. but if it is RHEL v6x it works fine..!!

Comment: It's not really logical that it's working inside your container on one OS and not on the other. Docker is pretty independent of on which OS you are running. When you pull an image from dockerhub and run it somewhere you should be able to run it on every OS with the right docker version. So I don't think your issue is an OpenShift issue.